# Node express server stops responding (timed out) very often

Tags: node.js, express, pm2

My project is almost a year old and was running very smoothly but from the past 2 months I am facing a server timeout issue, all the requests are going timed out after a while like 3 to 4 times a day. On PM2 restart it starts working fine again.

[image: terminal schreenshot]

```
Specs : 
NODE V -  9.8.0 
PM2 V -  2.10.1 
EC2 instance -  M4 Large
```

Comment: Can you add more details, like database uses , any specific API calls. Are there any other services like DB, logging etc running in you instance etc.

Comment: @damitj07 There are no any specific Api's on which server is hanging up its very random.
And I am using Mysql database.

Comment: Can you take a heap dump of you node process. This will help you in analyszing if it is a code issue or something else. As I can see your instacne size is pretty big.

Comment: sorry I don't follow you could you please explain a bit @damitj07